# UINavigationBar setTitleTextAttributes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, titlebar

I'm trying to change the color of NavigationBars title while I'm on a viewcontroller (not before pushing it). by using:

```
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes];
```

But this line of code only works before pushes or pops. I was wondering if there is a way to force this without navigating?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the simplest way is to create an `UILabel` with the same style you want for the `UINavigationController` title and set the label to the `navigationItem.titleView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
UILabel * label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,45,45)] autorelease];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = self.navigationItem.title;
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

create custom label and set it as titleView of your navigation bar